How to set JSON value to Contact record with Flow
Using a Salesforce Platform Event, the JSON value is entered into Salesforce Flow with a 'Platform Event Trigger Flow'.
I would like to parse the JSON value and create a Contact record, mapping 'ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__FirstName__c' to 'First Name' and 'ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__LastName__c' to 'Last Name' in the Contact record.
I can select {!$Record.PayloadCurrentValue} in 'Extract JSON Values' but cannot parse the nested values like 'ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__FirstName__c', which prevents me from creating the record using the JSON value.
How can I set the values from JSON to the Contact record?
{
   "PayloadCurrentValue":"{
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_Home_org_Contact_ID__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_KQ_Id__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__BirthDateDay__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__BirthDateMonth__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__BirthDateYear__c\":2001.000000000000000000,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__BirthDate__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__CreatedDate__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__DataSourceId__c\":\"MCIS_abc123\",
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__DataSourceObjectId__c\":\"users\",
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__FirstName__c\":\"John\",
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__GenderId__c\":\"Male\",
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__GenderIdentity__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__Id__c\":\"956660192fed52b319188937\",
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__InternalOrganizationId__c\":\"nto\",
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__LastModifiedDate__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__LastName__c\":\"Doe\",
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__PersonName__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__PhotoURL__c\":null,
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__PrimaryLanguageId__c\":\"English\",
      \"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__Salutation__c\":null
   }",
   "SourceObjectDeveloperName":"ssot__Individual__dlm",
   "EventType":"CDCEvent",
   "PayloadPrevValue":"",
   "PayloadSchema":null,
   "PayloadMetadata":"{\"ChangeEventHeader\":{\"changedFields\":[\"ssot__Individual__dlm_ssot__BirthDateYear__c\"],
   \"commitTimestamp\":\"2024-06-05 11:48:20.903\",
   \"commitVersion\":\"504\"}}",
   "EventCreationDateTime":"2024-06-05T11:50:02Z",
   "ActionDeveloperName":"Create_Exit_User_Action",
   "EventPrompt":"UPDATE",
   "Offset":"26729",
   "EventPublishDateTime":"2024-06-05T11:50:04Z",
   "CreatedById":"005Ho00000Aaig8IAB",
   "CreatedDate":"2024-06-05T11:50:04Z",
   "EventSchemaVersion":"1"
}

